# How do I configure redirects in vite?

Tags: vuejs3, vite, bitrix

So basically I'm trying to migrate from Vue-cli to vite and I need to find an alternative to

```
module.exports = {
    publicPath: '',
    devServer: {
    setup(app) {
        app.post('*', (req, res) => {
        res.redirect(req.originalURL);
        });
    },
  },
    lintOnSave: false
};
```

for developing apps with Bitrix api